# Does Facebook always choose the picture in the head for thumbnail?

Tags: facebook

I have a logo image set in the head of [my home page](http://tenbooksamonth.com/), but for some reason, when I use the share button for Facebook, the image Facebook chooses is a picture from elsewhere on the page.  Is there a reason for this?  Can I change it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Visit this link: [A Guide to Sharing for Webmasters](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters)

I guess if you change or paste this code between the "head" tags then facebook will show the correct image

```
<meta property="og:image"              content="http://tenbooksamonth.com/example.jpg" />
```

Also You can check your details [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/)

I hope it helps

Comment: If you check the way the page is rendering, the correct tags are there.  I checked your suggersted "You can check your details here" link, and apparently Facebook sees the tags, but is still choosing a different image.  Shrug.

Comment: Oh this is so weird.  I'm sorry.  I edited my comment, but the edits must have submitted after the allowed time window.  What I said was... The tags were there and were correct, but thanks to your "Also You can check your details here" link, I was able to see that Facebook thought that the image I provided was too small.  So thank you so much.  Other than tinkering for improvements, it's fixed.  (I tried to give you an up arrow, but I'm not able to rate yet... Too new to forum apparently.) Thank you again.  Really helped me out.